# auto-detecting components using spring annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I've managed to configure to spring to auto-detect my components using the @Autowire 
annotation.  However the problem is that not all the components are being Auto wired.
Specifically My DAO's are being bound but my service objects aren't.  I have to explicitly 
create a bean for my service object in the spring xml config file.

Any clue as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If spring is not complaining about anything but it's still not being wired, there are a few probable causes, from most to least likely:

- The service implementation is missing the proper annotation; i.e @Component, @Controller, @Service or one of the other annotations.
- If the implementation is not annotated it has to be present as an xml bean definition.
- The classpath-scan you have set up in the xml file does not hit the service.
- Your jar file with services is packed without directory structure.